# How to align the drawer navigation items to bottom of the screen in react native?

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, navigation-drawer

I have a drawer navigation with permanent drawer type and I want to align the drawer items to bottom of the screen instead of the top.
Like this photo:
[image: Drawer Navigation]

The code I used to align the did not work for me:

```
drawerStyle: {
        backgroundColor: '#000',
        width: 80,
        justifyContent:'flex-end',
        alignItems:'flex-end'
      },
```

Answer (score 1):

Code for: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ulr2r.png

```
export default function App() {
  const renderTabIcon = (sourceIcon) => () => {
    return (
      <Image
        style={{
          height: 20,
          width: 20,
          resizeMode: "contain",
        }}
        source={sourceIcon}
      />
    );
  };

  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Drawer.Navigator
        initialRouteName="Home"
        screenOptions={{
          drawerStyle: {
            width: 57,
          },
          drawerContentStyle: {
            flexDirection: "column-reverse",
          },
          drawerLabel: "",
        }}
      >
        <Drawer.Screen
          name="Home"
          component={HomeScreen}
          options={{
            drawerIcon: renderTabIcon(require("./home.png")),
          }}
        />
        <Drawer.Screen
          name="Search"
          component={SearchScreen}
          options={{
            drawerIcon: renderTabIcon(require("./search.png")),
          }}
        />
      </Drawer.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}
```

More information: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/drawer-navigator/#screenoptions

Comment: It works for me. 
I have another question too.
How to align the drawer label and icon vertically as it is horizontally aligned by default?

Comment: @Mahdi You want Drawer Menu drop from top to bottom, not left to right(or right to left), right?

Comment: I want to design a sidebar menu like this menu.
https://dribbble.com/shots/6987253-Netflix-Redesign-App
Please visit this link and guide me how to design that.

Comment: @Mahdi I modified my example(image and code). please check it.

Comment: If your problem resolved, please mark it resolved.

Comment: The edited section did not work.

Comment: what error did you received?

Comment: Look in my comments, I have shared a link with you. I want to have a navigation like that. But I dont know how to create that with react native.

Comment: When you try my example(edited), you have an error. What is your error?

I will share my source code tomorrow, I'm using Expo to build.

Comment: There is no error, but the result is different.

Comment: oh. your mean Drawer in my example have position opposite to your design?